# How to read struct members from another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a struct in my mainwindow class:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "dialog.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    struct properties{
      int ID = -1;
    };

    properties ret_func();
  private slots:
    void on_btn1_clicked();

  private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    properties _properties;
    Dialog *_dialog;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I set value to it's memeber in `mainwindow.cpp` by clicking on `btn1`:

```
MainWindow::properties MainWindow::ret_func()
{
  return _properties;
}

void MainWindow::on_btn1_clicked()
{
  _properties.ID = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
  qDebug()<<_properties.ID;
  _dialog->exec();
}
```

by clicking on `btn1` another window is opened and I want to read the struct member value by clicking on `btn2`. This is my code:

```
void Dialog::on_btn2_clicked()
{
    qDebug()<<MainWindow::ret_func().ID;//->this line has error
}
```

Error:

```
error: cannot call member function 'MainWindow::properties 
MainWindow::ret_func()' without object
 qDebug()<<MainWindow::ret_func().ID;
                                ^
```

I have read some threads having similar problems but couldn't find solution
please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, there's way too much info that the reader needs to filter, making your question bad. Please extract a [mcve] from your code before posting here!

Answer (score 2):

`MainWindow::ret_func()`is not a static member, this is why the compiler says *error: cannot call member function .. without object*

You need to have the instance of *MainWindow* to apply `ret_fun`on it.

If you have only one *MainWindow* you can modify that class to be a *singleton* to be able to do `MainWindow::instance().ret_func().ID;MainWindow::ret_func().ID;`

Comment: thank you for your reply. but your answer made me more confused.I'm a newbie and don't know what is singleton! searched on the web but couldn't understand it.would you edit my code? my poor english is another reason too.

Comment: A singleton is a class having exactly one instance, and a static member typically named _instance_ returning that instance. But I cannot know how many instance of MainWindow you have and if it can be a _singleton_

Comment: there is no other way?is it possible to make 'MainWindow::ret_func()' a static member to eliminate error?

Comment: @rezamoslemi you can also add a method in your class _Dialog_ to give it the instance in `MainWindow::on_btn1_clicked()` for instance doing `dialog_->setWindow(this);` before `_dialog->exec();`. But frankly globaly the  ways you do is very strange

Comment: @rezamoslemi if 'MainWindow::ret_func()'  is static that one will not be able to reach non static members, you just push the problem